# How many subgroups of orders $3$ and $6$ are there in a non-cyclic Abelian group of order $18?$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

How many subgroups of orders $3$ and $6$ are there in a non-cyclic Abelian group of order $18$?

Comment: Your first equation is wrong. $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ is **not** isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: Also... your final line makes no sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is one noncyclic abelian group of order $18$, isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

These are the subgroups of order $6$. They are cyclic.
$$ \{(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (0,1,1), (0,2,0), (0,2,1)\}. $$
and
$$ \{(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (1,0,0), (1,0,1), (2,0,0), (2,0,1)\}. $$

As for subgroups of order $3$, well, these have to be generated by elements of order $3$. There are four elements of order $3$ in this group, $(0,1,0), (0,2,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0)$. These generate two distinct subgroups of order $3$.

Comment: This answer has been accepted but both parts are wrong.